# Deploying binaries from Bamboo to Nexus repository

Tags: nexus, bamboo

Firstly I am new to Nexus. So please bear if it is too noob a question. Let me first explain how our current build/deployment process works.

HOW WE DO IT AT PRESENT:

We have a project that is Maven based. There is a parent POM.xml and two module pom.xmls Each child module POM.xmls create a JAR file each when built. Currently I am doing the build/ deployments manually. I checkout code from SVN to my local machine. I run mvn clean install. I  have created a bash script to bundle the 2 Jar files + few other resources (Present just in SVN repo and gets downloaded to local) into a tar.gzip file. Now I SCP this to the app server. Run install scripts that deploys the tar.gzip file.

HOW WE WANT TO DO IT:

We plan to automate the build in Bamboo (Which I have already done). Then the built artifact needs to be uploaded to a Nexus repository (Due to security issues, the SCP task in Bamboo does not work because of establishing SSH connectivity from Bamboo Server to App Server).

MY FIRST HURDLE:

I have created a Bash Script task in Bamboo which does the bundling ( 2 Jars from each child Module POM + resources) to a tar.gzip. This tar.gzip is prersent in a path a/b/c/d on my bamboo machine.

How do I upload this tar.gzip to Nexus Repository?

MY CONFUSION:

I have read about uploading artifacts to Nexus. But I understand it if just 1 jar/ear/war file is created from the build. But we want the bundle. So if I make changes to settings.xml & POM.xml to configure the upload to NEXUS, each JAR file will be uploaded into separate paths in Nexus. And then I have to configure separately to upload the resource files (Not part of build). Is my understanding correct? Please let me know how to proceed with this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: advice: when asking a question try to make it short and clear. people don't like reading "walls of text".....

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to create an assembly that contains your artifacts and resources, and then your regular maven deploy will deploy it into Nexus.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help in this. If I do the bundle using a bash script task instead of the maven assembly Plugin (To avoid making changes to POM), then will mvn Deploy work? Again thanks a ton for your quick response.